# How to solve ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'fortinet.fortios.fortios_system_policy'

Tags: ubuntu, automation, ansible, fortigate

I am trying to run a playbook in Ansible to FortiGate for example this playbook that will enable like to create a security policy but everytime I run the playbook this message shows

```
"ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'fortinet.fortios.fortios_system_policy'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path."
```

What should I do?

The playbook:

```yaml
- name: Add Firewall Policy
  hosts: fortigate
  connection: network_cli
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    fortigate_vdom: root

  tasks:
    - name: Configure system policy
      fortinet.fortios.fortios_system_policy:
        vdom: "{{ fortigate_vdom }}"
        policyid: 1
        name: "Allow_HTTP"
        srcintf: "port2"
        dstintf: "port3"
        srcaddr: "all"
        dstaddr: "all"
        action: accept
        status: enable
```

I don't really understand the meaning of modules, I am beginner in Ansible so I will be glad if someone help me and explain it to me.

I don't get the FortiOS modules I tried to follow the instructions on internet but nothing works the same error message over and over.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Modules are like "libraries" in Ansible. Some modules are available by default in Ansible, such as the ones included under the `ansible.builtin` namespace. Examples: [ansible.builtin.copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) or [ansible.builtin.lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html)

However, some modules need to be installed first. In your case:

```
ansible-galaxy collection install fortinet.fortios
```

This said the module `fortinet.fortios.fortios_system_policy` does not seem to exist:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/fortinet/fortios/index.html

Comment: i already installed the modules using ansible-galaxy collection install fortinet.fortios but i keep getting the same error message the fortios is not known

Comment: Check the URL I sent you. That module does not seem to exist. Maybe you need to install an older version of the collection